# Language vs class-level reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I was reading [this article](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue273.html) when I stumbled on two terms: language reflection and class-level reflection:

> When I lamented about this on Twitter, Brian Goetz picked up on it and explained that I was trying to do language-level reflection. Instead, I should see it as class-level reflection. This is true, of course. If I had written List.class.getMethod("size") all of the list objects would have happily volunteered their size.

Can you tell me, what the difference between those two is and what does it have to do with the following code raising `IllegalAccessException`:

```
Collection<String> col = List.of("Goetz", "Marks", "Rose");
col.getClass().getMethod("size").invoke(col);
```

Comment: I interpret the statement as that "class-level-reflection" only looks on the class itself, the caller is not considered in the consideration if a method is found. "language-level refelection" would follow the rules of the language of visiblity (also with methods of nested classes) and polymorphism.